# How to rate limit using iptables Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables

I'm trying to solve the question how to rate limit access for IP to our Ubuntu server. I would love to block if someone requests too much frequently our API endpoint, or in general if hits too much frequently the port(s) of service(s). I tried to understand how to solve this using iptables but I don't know the better configuration to block who requests too many times the resources/API:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6000 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
```

Could you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your rules above look correct but incomplete to me.

It may be that you dont have a default drop rule after the allow rules, or it may be these rules have been added after an accept rule so they are never being hit. (Rule ordering is very important in iptables).

Using "iptables -vnL" could be useful as it can show the amount of traffic each rule matchesand also the order the rules are in.

Comment: Thanks, so with these could I limit to 25 (or other value to set) requests for a single IP in a minute? Do you suggesto put these as first one and then the accept one?

Comment: Not sure what you are saying in your comment. You need a drop rule at the end  not  an allow.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.103 -m limit --limit 128k -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.131 -m limit --limit 128k -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.126 -m limit --limit 128k -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.103 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.131 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.126 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.103 -j LIMIT_DOWNLOAD
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.131 -j LIMIT_DOWNLOAD
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.126 -j LIMIT_DOWNLOAD
iptables-save
```